# Listview doesn't update while inserting data into Database

Tags: android, android-listview

My question is about Updating listview after data changed in SQLite Database.My Listview doesn't updated when i insert data into databse.On my onRestart() i want to do something like this:

```
onRestart(){
super.onRestart();
custom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It gives me NullPointerException.
But instead of this i have to write full code:

```
onRestart(){
super.onRestart();
cursor.requery();
listview.setadapter(custom_adapter);
listview.setonClickListener(new OnclickListener(){
......
}
)};
}
```

My custom listview contains Imageview and Two TextView.

Comment: You could send a select query to the SQLiteDatabase and put the returned records in a DataTable, then fill the Listview with the DataTable, every time after you Updated something in the database

Comment: Thanks..Its works..I have done like this:cursor.requery():

Answer (score 0):

Calling the  `notifyDataSetChanged()` method from the **Adapter** checks changes in the `list<Objects>` that was received in the **Adapter constructor**, so changing data in sql database is not the point, you have to make sure that you changed the data in the same `List<Object>` that u sent to the **Adapter**. in that case the `listView` will refresh automatic